# Replace checkboxes while exporting grid to excel

Tags: c#, excel, gridview

I don't want to show checkboxes when I export my grid to excel. I header checbox doesn't show while all child chechboxes are always there.. :( I debug and found out the reason that gridview concat its own id in name to each row so that my code couldn't detect checkboxes. here is my code

```
 protected void Export_to_Excel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataSource = dtPatientList;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PatientSearchReport.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xlsx";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        string html2 = Regex.Replace(stringWrite.ToString(), @"(<input type=""image""\/?[^>]+>)", @"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        html2 = Regex.Replace(html2, @"(<input type=""checkbox""\/?[^>]+>)", @"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        html2 = Regex.Replace(html2, @"(<a \/?[^>]+>)", @"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Response.Write(html2.ToString());
        Response.End();
        GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
        GridView1.DataSource = dtPatientList;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: can you make the ClientIdMode static for checkboxes and then retry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
protected void Export_to_Excel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PatientSearchReport.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xlsx";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);  
        GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        string html2 = Regex.Replace(stringWrite.ToString(), @"(<input type=""image""\/?[^>]+>)", @"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        html2 = Regex.Replace(html2, @"(<input class=""checkbox""\/?[^>]+>)", @"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        html2 = Regex.Replace(html2, @"(<a \/?[^>]+>)", @"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Response.Write(html2.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```